# Understanding MultiTouch / PointerIndex's / PointerId's in android?

Tags: java, android, multi-touch

I keep getting an pointerIndex out of range Error on line 71. I'm new to using MultiTouch and have looked at many examples and tutorials dealing with pointer ids and pointer indexs but im still a little confused by it. I've also looked over some of the postsing on here about pointerIndex out of range Threads which I thought would clear up some of the confusion but to no luck. I'm trying to make a drag and pinch zoom The code listed here is an example of what im trying to do.

Here is my onTouchEvent code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    int action = e.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    int DRAG = 0;
    int ZOOM = 1;
    int NONE = 2;
    float X;
    float Y;
    int gesture = NONE;
    int dragPointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    int zoomPointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    int dragPointerIndex;
    int zoomPointerIndex;

    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        gesture = DRAG;
        dragPointerId = e.getPointerId(0);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        gesture = ZOOM;
        zoomPointerId = e.getPointerId(1);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        gesture = NONE;
        dragPointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        gesture = NONE;
        zoomPointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (gesture == ZOOM) {
            zoomPointerIndex = e.findPointerIndex(zoomPointerId);
            X = e.getX(zoomPointerIndex);
            Y = e.getY(zoomPointerIndex);
            Coords2.setText(X + "," + Y);
        } else if (gesture == DRAG) {
            dragPointerIndex = e.findPointerIndex(dragPointerId);
            X = e.getX(dragPointerIndex);/////////////////////// Line 71
            Y = e.getY(dragPointerIndex);
            Coords1.setText(X + "," + Y);
        }
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is the logcat Error:

```
    07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:1974)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at com.example.touchex.MainActivity.onTouch(MainActivity.java:71)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5565)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1951)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1712)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2084)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1542)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2483)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2031)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5750)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2910)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2486)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:853)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2495)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4586)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-23 03:16:21.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23096):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: at com.example.touchex.MainActivity.onTouch(MainActivity.java:71)
what does exist at line 71 ?

Comment: Line 71 is this in the code i've even comminted when line 71 is in the code:   X = e.getX(dragPointerIndex);

Comment: `dragPointerIndex = e.findPointerIndex(dragPointerId);`  make sure `dragPointerIndex` is not null or invalid

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: what is yoru `dragPointerId` ? in some previous case you write `dragPointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;` which causes dragpointer get the value -1, so you might once get -1 as index and then at second time you wrote this `e.findPointerIndex(dragPointerId);` since `dragPointerId` is -1 it will give you error, can you log value of your `dragpointerId`

Comment: Ah ok I'll give that a try.